# C - how to add a char to an array

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, char, malloc

I'm trying to figure out how to add a simple `char` to an array created with `malloc`.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
    char *array = malloc(2);
    array[0] = "h";
    printf("%s", array);
    return 0;
}
```

It gives the warning:

```
 warning: assignment makes integer from pointer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]
array[0] = "h";
```

and if I run the program anyway, it just prints out 3 random symbols.

Comment: `array[0]='h'; array[1]='\0'` or `strcpy(array, "h");`

Comment: It is a pity the compiler does not reject this bogus code with an error. `gcc -Wall -W -Werror` is your friend.

Comment: `array` is not an array, it is a *pointer* to an array. `malloc()` does not *create* an array, it allocates one. You are not *adding* a character to the array, you want to assign or set a `char` element of the array.

Comment: `memcpy(array, "h", 2)` instead of `array[0] = "h";`, would work (2 is the length, where  you'd be copying two bytes to include the trailing '\0' char (byte)). The name of the array pointer, is the same as address of the two bytes of memory you allocated. It would also work if you'd done `char array[2];` followed by the same `memcpy`. For such a small case it would be more practical to skip malloc() and memcpy() but this is just to illustrate a point. For something this small you'd do what @kaylum suggested. BTW: Bad practice to not explicitly call `free()` to release memory before exit.

Comment: Regarding last comment: I used the number 2 literally, but when passing lengths to `memcpy()` and I/O calls, etc... typically you use `sizeof()` to refer to the size of the item or use a named constant. Bad practice to use strictly numeric arguments as it makes it harder to debug what your code is doing.   The OS *will* free your memory when the program exits but you should always be in the habit of thinking about where you'll put your `free()` call(s) whenever you do `malloc()`. It's a common bad habit to `malloc()` and not free memory and create *leaks*. ALWAYS be careful w/`malloc()`!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're assigning a string to a character. Instead, assign a character:

```
array[0] = 'h';
```

After that you need to null-terminate your string:

```
array[1] = '\0';
```

Alternatively, you can copy the string in using `strcpy`:

```
strcpy(array, "h");
```

Answer (score 0):

For starters in this statement

```
array[0] = "h";
```

there is used a string literal instead of a single character (integer) `'h'`. The string literal is converted to pointer to its first character. So in this statement you are trying to assign a pointer to a character.

You have to use a character literal like

```
array[0] = 'h';
```

But in this case the array will not contain a string because the second character of the array is not initialized and has indeterminate value. And the conversion specifier `%s` is used to output strings.

So You need to append one more statement like this

```
array[1] = '\0';
```

Or you could initially to use `calloc` instead of `malloc`.

```
char *array = calloc(2);
```

and then it will be enough to write

```
array[0] = 'h';
```

If you want to use the string literal then instead of the assignment you should use the standard C function `strcpy` like

```
strcpy( array, "h" );
```

to copy the string literal into allocated dynamically array.

You should free the allocated memory when the array is not needed any more.

```
free( array );
```

Answer (score -4):

`array[0]` is a `char&`.
`"h"` is a `const char[2]`.
You cannot assign an array of `char` to a `char` reference.
You probably wanted `array[0] = 'h';`, since `'h'` is a `const char`.

Comment: What's a reference? And what's the `&` after the `char`?